# FFT index of vertical spatial frequency

Tags: image-processing, fft, frequency

Hi I have some problem with the following:

I have f(x,y), a 64x64 image coming from a sensor chip. I would like to use a filtering approach in the frequency domain and hence I zero pad the image f(x,y) by a factor 4 and then multiply it by (-1)(x+y). The resulting image is then run through a 2D FFT. I can assume that all indices start at 0. Now the question is: At what FFT index would I now find the vertical spatial frequency of +20 cycles per original chip side length?

Well ok. I have my 64x64 image and zero pad it so that I then have a 128x128 image. Is that correct? Now I don't understand what exactly the vertical spatial frequency of +20 cycles is.

Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why padding? Why that multiplication? (Is that supposed to be a power, by the way?) it’s so much easier if you just FFT the image as it is...

Comment: One needs to zero-pad before the FFT and filtering in the frequency domain, or else you get circular convolution (wrap around artifacts) which is rarely what one wants.

Comment: yes sorry, that should be a power. its written in the task that i have to zero pad it..